# Reset numbers in SQL customer table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have customer table with ID the numbers are ok until 800 after there is jump to

```
8001
8002
then another jump
80003
80004
```

I need to reset the numbers from 800 and 0n like that:

```
800 - this ok
```

Now I need to replace the 8001 to 801

```
8002 - 802
```

and on to all the remain numbers

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I would be more interested in root cause since it may just happen again after you fix.

Comment: Is this an auto-increment field? And have you removed certain rows which may have led to the jump?

Comment: hi its an user mistake if it happen again i fix that again now i need to resolve this problem

Comment: no its not auto incerment

Comment: Well 8000-7200 = 800 ..

Comment: You have to be careful if this Customer ID is referred to in any other table

Comment: yes I know that thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can re-assign all the numbers using variables or a `join`:

```
set @rn := 800

update t
    set id = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    where id >= 800
    order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba1138317fe906b4290d5dff6af08488) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: there is a problem with this line :
set id = (@rn = @rn + 1) the = make the err

Comment: @Techman . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  This does exactly what your question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

WITH "CTE-NUM"
AS
(
Select CID , tempID,
    102 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CID) AS Rank1
    FROM CUST WHERE CID > 102
)
UPDATE "CTE-NUM" SET CID = Rank1